# How do I update nested MongoDB object

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have been stuck on this for 6 hours now... How do I update a field inside an object inside and element that is inside another object in MongoDB.

So I have a collection of users, each user is one document which contains arrays of objects. These objects have fields that i want to be able to change. Like i want to change just the "frequency" and "status" field but i want to change only the one with an "_id" equal to a query.

I've tried

```
db.collections.users.updateOne(
  {},
  {$set: {"nouns.$[element].status": 3}},
  {multi: true,
  arrayFilters: [{"element._id": req.body.inputId}]}
);
```

Plus a lot of other things.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5f7d8490c1842471c6bcea42"),
"username" : "eric@mail.com",
"nouns" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f7d849cc1842471c6bcea43"),
        "word" : "die Sonne",
        "timeStamp" : ISODate("2020-10-07T09:04:28.436Z"),
        "frequency" : 0,
        "status" : 0
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f7d84a8c1842471c6bcea45"),
        "word" : "das Wetter",
        "timeStamp" : ISODate("2020-10-07T09:04:40.940Z"),
        "frequency" : 0,
        "status" : 0
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f7d84afc1842471c6bcea47"),
        "word" : "der Apfel",
        "timeStamp" : ISODate("2020-10-07T09:04:47.403Z"),
        "frequency" : 0,
        "status" : 0
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f7d84b9c1842471c6bcea49"),
        "word" : "das Maedchen",
        "timeStamp" : ISODate("2020-10-07T09:04:57.388Z"),
        "frequency" : 0,
        "status" : 0
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f7d84c8c1842471c6bcea4b"),
        "word" : "das Auto",
        "timeStamp" : ISODate("2020-10-07T09:05:12.036Z"),
        "frequency" : 0,
        "status" : 0
    }
],
"verbs" : [],
"adjectives" : [],
"others" : [],
"salt" : "*****",
"hash" : "*****",
"__v" : 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query work well, try it on this [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hDSOjFd7JgO)

`req.body.inputId` has to be an ObjectId to match the `_id` in `nouns`

Comment: It does work! I have just one problem. How do I put the ObjectId into the field. The console says error ObjectId is not defined. When I call req.body.inputId it is only the string that is inside the ObjectId brackets.

Comment: I figured it out! I declare const ObjectId = require('mongodb').objectID

Comment: Please provide also the code with your answer. The shared content may disappear in future. "Link only" answer are not appreciated here.

Comment: My link is just a copy/paste of the request given in the question. I put it on MongoPlayground to try the query and see that it's working

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... Thanks to AlexisG for giving me the clue that I needed an ObjectId and not just a string ID from inside the ObjectId brackets.

Solution was to declare at the start of the js file:
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').objectID

and then in arrayFilters:[{"element._id": ObjectId(req.body.inputId)}]